# What limits the top speed in curves?

Tags: speed, centrifugal-force, adhesion

I was asking myself how it would be possible to set new top speeds on racetracks. I came to the conviction that on most tracks not the vehicle with the highest top speed have the fastest laptime.
Breaking, driving curves and accelariting have the greatest influence.

So how can you drive curves without loosing speed or loosing less speed.
In a curve the centrifugal force works again the adhension of the tires with the road. If the centrifugal force gets to strong the tires loose grip and you fly out of the curve.

So there are 2 ways to optimize curve speed. 
The first is to optimize the tires. This is usually done.

But the second way is to reduce the centrifugal force. This would be theoretically possible with little nozzles on the outside of the car, which gets activated while driving a curve and helps press the car in the inside of the curve.

Is this theoretically correct or am I missing an important fact?

I know that this is not practically in a large scale. But it would be interesting if this works and if its only one Test Car or in a sized down test.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Centripetal force]

In order for a car to negotiate a bend, a **centripetal** force $\vec{F}_c$ must act on it, otherwise it will not be able to stay on its trajectory. For an idealised (because circular) bend the magnitude of this force is given by:

$$F_c=\frac{mv^2}{R},$$

where $R$ is the radius of the bend, $m$ the car's mass and $v$ the car's speed: tighter bends (smaller $R$), higher mass and higher speed all necessitate higher **centripetal** force $\vec{F}_c$.

As you point out correctly, this force is provided by the friction of the car's tires on the road surface.

> This would be theoretically possible with little nozzles on the outside of the car, which gets activated while driving a curve and helps press the car in the inside of the curve.

'On paper' this is certainly possible. If nozzles were to provide thrust pointing leftwards (in the figure above), that force would supplement the friction forces provided by the tires. *All other things being equal*, the higher $F_c$ would then allow to negotiate the bend at higher speed.

How practical this is, considering such a device and the fuel it requires will add to the weight of the car, remains very much to be seen.

> What limits the top speed in curves?

Regardless of the car, a measure often used on race tracks, velodromes and even ordinary roads, is to give the road some inclination $\alpha$ towards the centre of the bend:

[image: Road inclination]

By decomposing the **weight** of the cat $mg$ as shown, we can see that one of the components points in the direction of the centre of the bend. This way, the weight of the car actually contributes to $F_c$.

Answer (score 1):

For a car to go around a corner an inward force has to be applied to produce the necessary centripetal acceleration.
The required force is **fixed** $(=\frac{mv^2}{r})$ by the mass of the car $m$, the speed of the car $v$ and the radius of the curve $r$.

So what you need to consider is how to provide this inward force.

Your idea about nozzles could produce part or all of the necessary force but note that another car on the same side as the nozzles might not be too keen on this.

> The first is to optimize the tires.

Tyres alone are not the answer.
What you need to do is the have the necessary frictional forces between the tyres and the road to provide the inward force.
The frictional force can be markedly increased by having a downforce on the car which depends on the geometry of the car.
The geometry of the car also has to be such that the car does not roll over whilst going around a bend.

Banking a road will also contribute to the inward force because the normal reaction on the car due to the road will have an inward force component.
The steeper the baking the greater is the inward force and so the car can go around a corner faster.
Have you ever been on a train which has stopped on a bend and noted that the train is leaning over due to the track being banked?

Motorways/highways are also banked but  extreme banking (in excess of $30^\circ) is to be found to race tracks.

So you have a fixed amount of force that is needed to make a car go around a corner and then need to consider how to provide this force.